# Must one generally go through libclang to generate LLVM IR - or is it possible to emit IR directly?

Tags: compiler-construction, llvm

I've written a bytecode compiler and stack-based VM for my own language using Rust. I was thinking of adding an extra step where I would go from the bytecode to LLVM IR to compile to machine code. I do realize that LLVM doesn't generate stack based code, which is fine. I'm willing to go to regsiter-based if needed.

Reading the LLVM docs, it appears that they recommend loading **libclang** and use their AST walker and functions that generate IR. Doing that seems to require that I re-write my AST in C/C++ so I can feed it to **libclang**. That just seems like a shame.

Do people learn the LLVM IR syntax and manually transpile to it? I though it might be a good way to understand the IR in detail. Is that commonly done?

Comment: No. Most compilers use ASTs of course, but there's no need to use clang's AST code or libclang. It is my impression that most compilers use LLVM in a fashion that resembles the code in [Kaleidoscope](https://llvm.org/docs/tutorial/) rather than that in clang. (IIRC there's an IR writer that writes .bc files without linking with *any* LLVM library, although I cannot remember its name.)

Comment: @arnt -Thanks for that. So at minimum, I must make FFI calls to the LLVM Builder class to generate the IR. That tells me that generating IR directly seems like it's discouraged

Comment: You don't need to use the builder. It is preferable, however. If you don't use the LLVM's builder, you effectively create your own ad-hoc builder anyway. MLton, for example, does this in its LLVM backend to avoid writing bindings. Similarly, the Haskell library llvm-hs-pure provides a way to construct LLVM IR without relying on LLVM to be present via FFI. If you're using Rust, you have inkwell and llvm-sys as popular choices for LLVM bindings.

Comment: IMO using the LLVM IRbuilder, using the classes directly that the builder uses, and doing something like what llvm-hs-pure are all reasonable approaches in some circumstances. It depends. Good luck.